# Angularjs : 2 different scopes with same object data sharing same behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array, treeview

I am making a nested tree structure with checkbox option in angularJs.

My object from the backend is as follows.

```
 {
"2": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Under Graduate",
    "slug": "under-graduate",
    "parent_id": 0,
    "level": 0,
    "path": "0",
    "show": false,
    "selected": false,
    "children": {
        "3": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "B.Com",
            "slug": "b-com",
            "parent_id": 2,
            "level": 1,
            "path": "2",
            "show": false,
            "selected": false,
            "children": {
                "4": {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Commerce",
                    "slug": "commerce",
                    "parent_id": 3,
                    "level": 2,
                    "path": "2\/3",
                    "show": false,
                    "selected": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have assigned the same object to 2 $scope variable with different names

```
$scope.a = object;
$scope.b = object;
```

Now i have used ng-repeat inside the **li** element  with ng-include as follows

```
<li ng-repeat="a in a.children" ng-include="'a_tree_renderer.html'"></li>
```

Using the same method with another variable(b)

```
<li ng-repeat="b in b.children" ng-include="'b_tree_renderer.html'"></li>
```

Inside both the template their is an option given to expand and view all the children.

Everything related to the tree algo works fine except when i perform this operation on one template ex. b, Somehow the template (a) index also changes, i.e if a expand an option from the second template the same thing on the first template expands, and vice versa.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what effect on the scope variable(s) the "operation" you mention has.

Comment: say $scope.a.show & $scope.b.show is equal to false, When i change $scope.b.show = true it changes $scope.a.show to true as well.

Comment: `$scope.a` and `$scope.b` refer to the same object, so changes to either will affect the other. If you want them to be independent, you may want to investigate [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assigning `$scope.a = object;` and `$scope.b = object;`, both `$scope.a` and `$scope.b` reference the same object. Therefore, modifying one of them will affect the other.

If you would like `$scope.a` and `$scope.b` to be independent, you could create a deep copy of the object so that each scope variable references a different copy of the object, by using [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy). That way, when you change anything on `$scope.a` or `$scope.b`, the other will not be affected.